# Integrate the improper integral (need help with limits part)

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

$$\int_{0}^{5} \frac{x}{x-2}dx = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 2} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \frac{x}{x-2}dx + \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 5} \int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{x}{x-2}dx$$

**U-substitution**:

$$u = x-2, du = dx \\ \int \frac{u+2}{u} = 1 + \frac{2}{u} \\\\ x + 2\ln|u| = \textbf{x + 2ln|x-2| + C}$$

Trying to evaluate the limit with $x + 2\ln|x-2| + C$. There is a singularity at $x = 2$. Here is what I tried to do...

$$\int_{0}^{5} \frac{x}{x-2}dx = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 2} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \frac{x}{x-2}dx + \lim_{\delta \rightarrow 5} \int_{0}^{\delta} \frac{x}{x-2}dx \\
= \epsilon + 2\ln|\epsilon-2| - 0 - 2\ln|-2| \\
+ 5 + 2\ln|5-2| - \epsilon - 2\ln|\epsilon -2| \\
= -2\ln|2| + 2\ln|3| + 5
$$

I am not really sure what I am doing here. I am not really sure how to tie everything up and show that the integral is convergent or divergent and if $-2\ln|2| + 2\ln|3| + 5$ is even the correct result to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, the singularity is at $2$. You can't “jump” over it: the integral is
$$
\int_0^2\frac{x}{x-2}\,dx+\int_2^5\frac{x}{x-2}\,dx
$$
provided *both* exist finite.

The first one is, with $x-2=t$,
$$
\int_{-2}^0\frac{t+2}{t}\,dt=
\lim_{\delta\to0^-}\int_{-2}^\delta\left(1+\frac{2}{t}\right)\,dt=
\lim_{\delta\to0^-}\Bigl[t+2\log\lvert t\rvert\Bigr]_{-2}^\delta=\infty
$$

Where's the author of the exercise trying to trip you up? If you just transform the integral into
$$
\int_{-2}^3\left(1+\frac{2}{t}\right)\,dt
\overset{\substack{\text{wrong}\\\downarrow}}{=}
\Bigl[t+\log\lvert t\rvert\Bigr]_{-2}^3=3+\log3-(-2+\log2)=5+\log3-\log2
$$
you'd make a big mistake. It's wrong because you're jumping over the singularity.

Comment: Hey, quick clarification about the $\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 2^-}$, my limit calculations are a bit rusty...how are you evaluating the limit of the integrand? Why is it going towards $\infty$ and why not a finite number here? I see $\delta \rightarrow 2$ so wouldn't there be a max value after you substitute in $\delta$ and $-2$ in for t?

Comment: @EvanKim Sorry, I realized just now that I wrote $\delta\to-2^-$ rather than $\delta\to0^-$. Fixed

Comment: Why are we checking $\lim_{-2}^{0}$ rather than $\lim_{0}^{-2}$? And I notice that in your last line with numbers, the integral becomes $\int_{-2}^{3}$ from the original $\int_{0}^{5}$

Comment: @EvanKim I performed the substitution $t=x-2$, so the bounds change.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

The integral should be:
$$\int_{0}^{5} \frac{x}{x-2}dx = \lim_{\epsilon \rightarrow 2^{-}} \int_{0}^{\epsilon} \frac{x}{x-2}dx +\lim_{\delta \rightarrow 2^{+}}\int_{\delta}^{5} \dfrac{x}{x-2}dx$$

Once you do this, the result should come out nicely.